# Nested dependent pattern-matching produces errors

Tags: pattern-matching, agda

Some imports and definitions first:

```
open import Relation.Binary.HeterogeneousEquality
open import Relation.Binary.PropositionalEquality
open import Data.Nat
open import Algebra
open import Data.Nat.Properties
module ℕCS = CommutativeSemiring commutativeSemiring

data Bin : ℕ → Set where
  zero  : Bin zero
  2*n   : ∀ {n} → Bin n → Bin (n + n)
  2*n+1 : ∀ {n} → Bin n → Bin (suc (n + n))

inc : ∀ {n} → Bin n → Bin (suc n)
inc zero = 2*n+1 zero
inc (2*n b) = 2*n+1 b
inc (2*n+1 {n} b) with n + suc n | ℕCS.+-comm n (suc n) | 2*n (inc b)
... | ._ | refl | b' = b'

nat2bin : (n : ℕ) → Bin n
nat2bin zero = zero
nat2bin (suc n) = inc (nat2bin n)
```

Now I want to prove this lemma:

```
lem : ∀ n → 2*n+1 (inc (nat2bin n)) ≅ inc (inc (2*n+1 (nat2bin n)))
lem zero = refl
lem (suc n) = {!!}
```

The following code produces an error:

```
lem : ∀ n → 2*n+1 (inc (nat2bin n)) ≅ inc (inc (2*n+1 (nat2bin n)))
lem zero = refl
lem (suc n)
    with suc (n + suc (suc n)) | ℕCS.+-comm (suc n) (suc (suc n))
... | ._ | refl = ?
```

Here it is:

```
suc (n + suc (suc n)) != w of type ℕ
when checking that the type
(n w : ℕ) (w₁ : w ≡ suc (suc (n + suc n))) →
2*n+1 (inc (inc (nat2bin n))) ≅
inc
(inc (2*n+1 (inc (nat2bin n))) | w | w₁
 | 2*n (inc (inc (nat2bin n))))
of the generated with function is well-formed
```

While this code typechecks perfectly:

```
postulate Foo : ℕ -> Set

foo : (m n : ℕ) -> Foo (m + n) -> Foo (n + m)
foo m n x with n + m | ℕCS.+-comm n m
... | ._ | refl = x

bar : (m n : ℕ) (x : Foo (m + n)) -> foo m n x ≅ x
bar m n x with n + m | ℕCS.+-comm n m
... | ._ | refl = refl
```

And this doesn't typecheck too:

```
qux : (n m : ℕ) -> (x : Foo (n + m)) -> foo m n (foo n m x) ≅ x
qux n m x with n + m | ℕCS.+-comm n m
... | ._ | refl = ?
```

The error:

```
n + m != w of type ℕ
when checking that the type
(n m w : ℕ) (w₁ : w ≡ m + n) (x : Foo w) →
(foo m n (foo n m x | w | w₁) | m + n
 | .Data.Nat.Properties.Simple.+-comm m n)
≅ x
of the generated with function is well-formed
```

What's going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

This is not really an answer to your specific question but: Your definitions look quite complicated. They don't really need to be that involved.

```
inc : ∀ {n} → Bin n → Bin (suc n)
inc zero = 2*n+1 zero
inc (2*n b) = 2*n+1 b
inc (2*n+1 {n} b) rewrite ℕCS.+-comm (suc n) n = 2*n (inc b)

lem : ∀ n → 2*n+1 (inc (nat2bin n)) ≅ inc (inc (2*n+1 (nat2bin n)))
lem n rewrite ℕCS.+-comm (suc n) n = refl
```